# How can I setup the various notifications to send to 2 destinations with Uber Eats API?

Tags: uber-api

I work for a point of sales company that wants to integrate Uber Eats into their systems. Is it possible to send all of the order notifications to us as well as to the merchants that uses our system?

I looked at the API documentation but I'm not too clear on what my next step(s) should be. I should also note that I'm not a developer, I'm gathering information for the development team.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to receive order notifications for both you and the merchants using your system.

There are several ways to achieve this:

Webhooks: Uber Eats offers an API that allows you to set up webhooks to receive real-time order notifications. You can find more information on how to do this in their API documentation(https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/webhook-orders-notification).

Zapier: If you're looking for a quicker and less technical solution, you can use Zapier to connect the Uber Eats API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).